# What's the difference between this two "default" material setups?

Tags: materials, node-editor, workflow

I watched a tutorial video that shows how to do bump mapping. I have tried to do what I saw in the video, but I found some a difference in new material creation.

When I press create a new material I get this:
[image]

When he presses the button he gets this
[image]

Why it is different?

Comment: The difference is render engine, switch from Blender Internal to Cycles renderer. It's the dropdown option on the top menu.